# Exception in thread "main" java.lang

Tags: java

I've been training a little with Java and I wanted to make this partial program about random numbers in a matrix 3x5, where every number in a column may belong to a different dozen compared to others.

I'll make a better explanation:

In one line you can have 9 and 11 but you can't have 11 and 13 because they belong to the same dozen (the 11-20 one). People who know the Tombola game will understand it.

But the main error after compiling and executing with cmd, was the one below, the exception in thread main java.lang.

So I hope you can help me: afterall I'm a new Java programmer.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index
>   0 out-of-bounds for length 0
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.remove(Unknown Source)
>           at Sheet.(Sheet.java:20)
>           at Sheet.main(Sheet.java:35)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
class Sheet{
private int[][] tab;
public Sheet(){
    int [][] tab=new int [3][5];
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int l=10; l<=90; l+=10){
        list.add(l);
    }
    Random rand=new Random();
    for(int m=0; m<3; m++){
        for (int n=0; n<5; n++){
            tab[m][n]=rand.nextInt(90);
            int o=(int)tab[m][m];
            if(list.contains(o*10)){
                break;
            }
            else{ 
                list.remove(0*10);
                n--;
            }
        }
    }
}
public void printSheet(){
    for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                System.out.println(tab[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    Sheet c=new Sheet();
    c.printSheet();
}
    }
```

Comment: `list.remove(0*10);`??

Answer (score 0):

You `remove` more numbers from `list` than you have `add`ed previously.

Adder loop

```
for(int l=10; l<=90; l+=10){
    list.add(l);
}
```

runs with l=10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90, so exactly 9 times.

Remover loop-pair

```
for(int m=0; m<3; m++){
    for (int n=0; n<5; n++){
        tab[m][n]=rand.nextInt(90);
        int o=(int)tab[m][m];
        if(list.contains(o*10)){
            break;
        }
        else{ 
            list.remove(0*10);
            n--;
        }
    }
}
```

Runs 3*5=15 times for starter, so may easily remove 15 elements, and because of the `n--` it potentially runs onto the `remove` call even more times. So you seem to remove a randomized and potentially high amount of elements from a list containing exactly 9 elements.

(Do note that `remove(x)` does not remove `x` from the list, but the xth element, in this case always the first one - which works for the first 9 attempts, then `list` is empty, having no first element, raising the exception you see)

Comment: I have read online and I saw that the remove method effectively removes that element from the list, like an array, integer,... Anyway that's a 3x5 table, allright, but the list is some kind of indicator that may help numbers, targetting it after being initialized, to get each one his own dozen for each line

Answer (score 0):

The cause for the Exception is the line

```
list.remove(0*10);
```

to check you can comment like the following and run

```
//list.remove(0*10);
```